# matplotlib power spectral density (PSD) value discrepancy

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I tried calculating the power spectral density using matplotlib function `psd()`. I plotted using two methods:

1. At first I plot it directly using `plt.psd` (red line in plot)
2. Then I output the values from `psd` to variables and plotting the
   variables (blue line in plot)

The code I used:

```
power, freqs = plt.psd(P * 100000, len(P), Fs = 1 / dt, scale_by_freq=0)
plt.psd(P * 100000, len(P), 1 / dt, scale_by_freq=0)
plt.plot(freqs, power)
```

But the plots are different, I expected it to be coincident. From where does the discrepancy arise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the implementation of `plt.psd` ([here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/80d05656551b63246cd3385ffed477c1ac25402d/lib/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py#L6104)) you can see that the log of the power is plotted.

Thus to get the same plot you have to call:

```
plt.plot(freqs, 10*np.log10(power))
```